# What's optimal march & mtune options for gcc for "Pentium4 and above" processors

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-optimization, compiler-options

My C++ application (compiled using g++) needs to work on Pentium-4 (32-bit) and above. However, it's typically used with Core2Duo or better processors.

I'm currently using: *-march=pentium4 -mtune=pentium4*. But some reading has prompted me to think that *-march=pentium4 -mtune=generic* might be better.

Can anybody shed some light on this? What are the optimal values for march & mtune options in this case?

Platform: GCC 4.1.2 on RHEL 5.3 (32-bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be `-march=pentium4 -mtune=core2`, as can be seen [on the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html).

Comment: Why did you select "-march=pentium4 -mtune=core2"? For which version is it the best? The newer gcc (4.6.1) has no problem with instruction scheduling for `arch=core2`.

Comment: The OP asked for something that would run on >= Pentium4 and be normally used on core2

Comment: i.e. -march=core2 includes instructions not available on Pentium4 and -mtune just controls instruction scheduling.

Comment: But is it any good to have -mtune=core2 when -march=pentium4, since only pentium4 compatible instruction set will be used anyway?

Comment: @Syam: `-mtune` changes instruction scheduling (i.e. how to order instructions to get optimal performance).